# Removing accents with Python - Unicode doesn't work

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to clean a spanish text with the following code:

```
import re
import unicodedata
file = open("dirty.txt").readlines()
archivo = open("cleanText.txt", "w")
textLowerCase = file[i].lower()
unicodeText = textLowerCase.decode('unicode-escape')
textWithoutAccents = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicodeText).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
textWithoutSymbols = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', textWithoutAccents)
archivo.write(textWithoutSymbols)
```

My input text is like:

```
"anunciarán la realización de una interpelación"
```

My desire output is:

```
"anunciaran la realizacion de una interpelacion"
```

But with my code i'm getting the next result:

```
"anunciarAn la realizaciA3n de una interpelaciA3n"
```

Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: Line 5: `NameError: name 'i' is not defined`

Comment: Why are you using `decode('unicode-escape')`? And is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add the line i = 0, but in the original code it's included

Comment: This is Python 2.7.. I've tried decode, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what **unidecode** package does: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

From the readme:

> The module exports a function that takes an Unicode object (Python 2.x) or string (Python 3.x) and returns a string (that can be encoded to ASCII bytes in Python 3.x):

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(u'ko\u017eu\u0161\u010dek')
'kozuscek'
>>> unidecode(u'30 \U0001d5c4\U0001d5c6/\U0001d5c1')
'30 km/h'
>>> unidecode(u"\u5317\u4EB0")
'Bei Jing '
```

EDIT:

Your exact example:

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode("anunciarán la realización de una interpelación")
'anunciaran la realizacion de una interpelacion'
```

EDIT 2:

If you are using Python 2, don't forget to either:

- `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, or:
- use `u` prefix before string quotes: `unidecode(u"anu...`